# STM32 send code directly to chip

Tags: microcontroller, stm32, stm32cubemx

I have just started in the world of stm32 microcontrollers and I have seen that they have many boards for debugging, testing, etc ...

But my question is the following.

If I develop software with STM32CubeMX for a certain stm32xxx.

Is it possible to design a board with this microcontroller and be able to send the previously developed software to your own board?

Comment: Of course it is possible. This is why they provide dev boards and reference designs - so you can copy the relevant parts to your design.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you would normally have some piece of hardware in between such as an ST-LINK (for ICSP) or a USB-Serial converter (to use the bootloader). Once the program is loaded you can disconnect the hardware.

Comment: To be clear, the ST-LINK is one particular implementation of the idea of an *SWD adapter*.  It happens to be ST's idea, but it's not the only solution which works with their chips, and happily not restricted to their chips either (though it has some quirks which make it a less than universal SWD solution).  Additionally the on-board ST-LINK on most ST demo & nucleo boards can be used with external targets of the same voltage, too.

Comment: @ChrisStratton Are there other solutions that work well with OP's choice of development tools? I know clones of the ST-LINK are very inexpensive, and the original is not particularly  pricey either, unlike Segger tools.

Comment: Essentially *any* SWD adapter works - CMSIS DAP, Raspberry Pi GPIO's, Blackmagic, to name some cheap improvisations... FT2232H, even used an ATMEL-ICE on STM's (though apparently only some adapter firmware versions work)

Comment: Some STM32 chips with USB also support firmware loading via USB using DFU. So even less hardware is needed.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany I am using a restricted version of ST-LINK with OpenOCD successfully to program BeagleBone board (that is TI processor). So I don't see why it won't work in the opposite direction

Comment: @SpehroPefhany.  Thanks for help